# Route when push notification is opened

Tags: c#, react-native, .net-core, azure-notificationhub

I am using React Native Azure Notification Hub library for our project, we have been troubling to navigate to particular app screen after click on remote push notification. How can i implement this with react native. Could you please help us with this issue, or show a way to solve this problem?

```
const NotificationHub = require('react-native-azurenotificationhub');
const PushNotificationEmitter = new NativeEventEmitter(NotificationHub);
const EVENT_REMOTE_NOTIFICATION_RECEIVED = 'remoteNotificationReceived';

useEffect(() => {
   PushNotificationEmitter.addListener(EVENT_REMOTE_NOTIFICATION_RECEIVED, _onRemoteNotification);
}, []);

function _onRemoteNotification(notification) {
    ...actions
}
```

Comment: Could you please share what you have tried or what errors you are getting? This will help greatly in troubleshooting your issue.

Comment: I don't get any errors, I actually want to know how I can route the user to a specific screen when they open a push notification. We understand notification information, when application is open. But how we can do same thing with React Native Azure Notification Hub library, when application close.